# Js (jquery) не проверяет "windows width" при открытии сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Когда я изменяю размер окна в chrome, то ссылка изменяется, а когда и сразу открываю сайт в этом разрешении, то он не работает, вот он сам:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() <= '1090') {
           $('.viber-href').attr("href", "то что мне нужно :D");
      }else {
        $('.viber-href').attr("href", "то что мне нужно :D");
      }
});
```

Comment: логично...у тебя же обработка привязана к событию ресайза а не к событию загрузки страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  ...
}).resize();
```

Comment: боже, какой я тупой. Спасибо )))

Comment: @RET1NO Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.